# Web Application User Interface development

Tags: django, user-interface, web

I am new in web application development, I would like to know what are the choices for developing the user interface for a an application such as an Inventory management system. for the backend, I am using python Django with MySQL but I would like to know if there are other technologies other than HTML, CSS, and JS for UI development.

I know that HTML, CSS, and JS are mostly used for website development but I am not sure if these are the recommended technologies for a web application where lots of user interaction is involved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use other technologies as well.

- React
- Vue.js
- Angular
- JQuery

**For Responsive website**

- Bootstrap
- Materialize css
- Semantic ui

**Further tutorials**

[Django + Angular = A powerful web application](https://medium.com/swlh/django-angular-4-a-powerful-web-application-60b6fb39ef34)

[Build a To-Do application Using Django and React](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-to-do-application-using-django-and-react)

[Creating an app with React and Django](https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-an-app-with-react-and-django/)

[CRUD App using Vue.js and Django](https://medium.com/quick-code/crud-app-using-vue-js-and-django-516edf4e4217)